# Facebook: get list of pages that a user is liked

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using the Javascript SDK.

I have a logged in user, and want to get back a list of page ids of all the pages that the user is likes.

Is there a way of doing this? The docs are pretty bad - and circular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/likes/

Do note that Facebook is very restrictive on the [`user_likes`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#reference-user_likes) permission that is required to access this endpoint. Facebook policies forbid "like gating" - requiring a user to like a page to access content or otherwise be rewarded.